# Set up locale for date-fns and Nextjs app directory

Tags: next.js, internationalization, server-side-rendering, date-fns, react-server-components

I'm using NextJS 13.4 with app directory (server components) and [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.30.0/docs/I18n). I also use next-intl as internationalisation library.

I want to set correct locale before the app starts rendering on server side and the user's timezone so that whatever is rendered on the server matches the browser rendered content.

```js
// arc/app/[locale]/layout.tsx
export default async function RootLayout({ children, params }: Props) {
  const locale = useLocale();

  // Show a 404 error if the user requests an unknown locale
  if (params.locale !== locale) {
    notFound();
  }

  // set locale for date-fns
  try {
    const dateFnsLocale = (
      (await import(`date-fns/locale`)) as Record<string, Locale>
    )[locale];
    setDefaultOptions({
      locale: dateFnsLocale,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("invalid locale for date-fns", { cause: error });
  }

...


  return (
    <html lang={locale}>
      <head />
      <body className={classNames(aeonicFontClassName, "text-tixy-1000")}>
        {children}
        <DateFnsLocaleLoader locale={locale} />
      </body>
    </html>
  );


// DateFnsLocaleLoader

"use client";

import { FC, useEffect } from "react";
import { setDefaultOptions } from "date-fns";

type Props = {
  locale: string;
};

export const DateFnsLocaleLoader: FC<Props> = ({ locale }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const load = async () => {
      try {
        const dateFnsLocale = (
          (await import(`date-fns/locale`)) as Record<string, Locale>
        )[locale];
        setDefaultOptions({
          locale: dateFnsLocale,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("invalid locale for date-fns", { cause: error });
      }
    };
    load();
  }, [locale]);

  return null;
};
```

The problem is that there is still mismatch between what is rendered on server vs client.